# Does Lombok EqualsAndHashCode Check Class Type

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, equals, lombok

Does Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode check class type/instance?

Edit: I'd like to mention that I work for a major company with their own framework, like many other companies, that we are restricted to. I do not have the ability to add libraries outside of our framework due to how intensive our security needs to be (many of you wouldn't have electricity in your state). So Lombok was just introduced into our framework recently (version 1.18.12 which wasn't even released until 2/20) as was Java 8 to give you another example of what I'm working with and the code/libraries I may have been exposed to. So please forgive me if I'm not extremely well versed in Lombok or that I've never heard of Delombok until it was mentioned in the comments.

Back to the question:

I've read https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode a few times and I keep coming out of it with different conclusions.

Here's an example of what I'm doing to help clarify my question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = GeneratorTypeA.VIEW)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class GeneratorTypeA extends AbstractGenerator {
    ...
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GeneratorA.seq.id")
    @Column(name = "GENERATOR_A_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

GeneratorTypeB would look exactly the same as the above code snippet. Now say I have the following:

```
final Set<GeneratorTypeA> generatorsA = ...;
final Set<GeneratorTypeB> generatorsB = ...;
```

Each entity only uses @EqualsAndHashCode.Include on the "id" parameter. I am using the below code to combine Set and Set into a single Set. Since I only explicitly wrote that the unique id should be used for equals, I could lose entities from both sets when I combine them unless Lombok also compares the "instance of" each object. So does anyone know if Lombok does this check (with onlyExplicitlyIncluded set to true - or in general) or if there is a way to utilize Lombok with the addition of this check?

Equivalent equals method I'd want to use without Lombok:

```
public boolean equals(final Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof GeneratorTypeA)) {
        return false;
    }
    final GeneratorTypeA castOther = (GeneratorTypeA) other;
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(getId(), castOther.getId()).isEquals();
}
```

The code I'm using to combine the sets works fine with this setup, but I'm working with a lot of data so the chances of running into duplicate unique identifiers used in the equals method is very low, but it opens the door for unintended functionality/bugs.

```
public static <T> Set<?> combine(final Set<?>... sets) {
    return Stream.of(sets).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the delomboked code?

Comment: Use [**Delombok**](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok). As the page says: "Delombok can of course also help understand what's happening with your source by letting you **look at exactly what lombok is doing 'under the hood'**".

Comment: I was unaware of Delombok. I wanted to see if someone could provide a simple yes/no answer. I don't exactly need to know the entirety of what the method is doing - just if it factors in the subclasses' types during equals comparison. I understand how equals/hashCode methods work. I don't have free time right now because I've been working 60hr/week for 2 months. I can't afford to sift through their entire library of code if someone could kindly provide a one word answer. That's all the question requires. I do appreciate you informing me of Delombok though - I can look at it when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the object is required to be an instance of `this` class.

As per the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode):

```
if (!(o instanceof EqualsAndHashCodeExample)) return false;
```

As an aside, it is ironic that your company is apparently so security conscious that it chose to wait many years before adopting java 1.8, but it waited so long that 1.8 was already end of life *before* you adopted it and support had already been terminated, leaving you exposed to unpatched security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I needed to know.

Comment: I agree @Bohemian but if half  the population's power can be turned off from a security flaw, you have to wait until the code has absolutely no flaws which could take years. We don't take on certain new libraries because they introduce bugs unintentionally so it's the same idea. We stick with the older libraries that haven't introduced security vulnerabilities. I completely agree though that the move the Java 8 was long overdue. Either way, I don't make the rules or the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok, generates equals and hashcode very well and you should not worry about that. However you should take care when you **override equals and hashcode** and you use these objects in the **Hash type collections** and (this is important to know) **the objects are not immutable**. Then you might have unexpected results. Let me show you with a concrete example:

```
public class SetTest  {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    static class User {
        private String name;
        private int age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
        User user1 = new User("Jane", 25);
        User user2 = new User("John", 40);
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);

        user1.setAge(26);
        users.add(user1);

        System.out.println(users);
    }
}
```

Answer: `[Task.SetTest.User(name=Jane, age=26), Task.SetTest.User(name=Jane, age=26), Task.SetTest.User(name=John, age=40)]`

As you can see, now you have in the set 3 objects instead of 2. This is happening because of the implementation of add from HashSet which works in this way:

1. when you add a new object, the hash code is computed
2. the hash code, identifies the bucket where all the objects with the same hash code (collision objects) are kept
3. an loop is done over all the objects from that bucket (if exists) and the objects are compare with equals
4. if the newly added objects matches one of the objects from the bucket, then the object is not added in the set, otherwise is added

In my case, after I changed the age of the user Jane, I changed the value of the hashcode, and the object was added in the collection because no other object with the same hashcode existed in the set.

Comment: I don't think I've ever found myself creating a situation like the one in your main() method so that's probably something I would have overlooked. It makes complete sense since, as you said, you changed the hash code before adding it to the set the second time. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Btw it is always better to create your objects immutable unless you really really need to have them mutable. For this, just put the internal object fields final and annotate the class with lombok @builder to generate a builder which lets you to create the object in a nice manner

Comment: Thanks @OctavianR - If I'm working with sets I always create objects in an immutable manner, especially if they're persistent entities, which is why I never thought of this. I have not seen the builder annotation before though so I'm definitely going to look into that. Thanks for another tip!